# Problem with getting byte array from stream in WCF Service

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

EDIT: Sorry Here was something tottaly wrong.

EDIT: again from the beginning:

I have a WCF Service and at some point of my program I am getting a pointer to a byte array. I want to copy bytes from this byte array / pointer to another byte array and send it to client.
I also have a test program (not WCF Service) that is running the same code:

```
            uint read = 1;
            uint size = (uint)job.OutputFileParameters[1].ActualSize + 1;
            byte[] arrbyt = new byte[job.OutputFileParameters[1].ActualSize + 1];
            unsafe
            {

                fixed (byte* buffer = arrbyt)
                {
                    int ind = 0;
                    while (read != 0)
                    {
                        str.RemoteRead(out *buffer, size, out read);

                    }

                }
            }
```

But in test program arrbyt is filled with bytes and everything is ok, but in WCF Service arrbyt is empty. This is my problem sorry for previous version i was tired ;)

Comment: As a note: `params` is a reserved keyword, not sure how you're using it without `@` being prefixed.

Comment: As another note, there are more problems with this: `size` and `read` aren't defined in the example, for one.

Comment: I can promise you that Marshal.Copy does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the same code has different result in WCF Service and in normal windows app. In WCF Service when RemoteRead reads 0 bytes it puts zeros to arrbyt, in Windows app after reading 0 bytes arrbyte stays as it was without any changes with proper values inside.